# Regex to split when uppercase after alphabetic lowercase char

Tags: java, regex, string

So I'm trying to split a string with a regex and the split function in java.
The regex should split the string when there is a capital letter after a noncapital letter like this

```
hHere      // -> should split to ["h", "Here"]
```

I'm trying to split a string like this

```
String str = "1. Test split hHere and not .Here and /Here";
String[] splitString = str.split("(?=\\w+)((?=[^\\s])(?=\\p{Upper}))");
/* print splitString */
// -> should split to ["1. Test split h", "Here and not .Here and not /Here"]
for(String s : splitString) {  
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output I get

```
1. 
Test split h
Here and not .
Here and /
Here
```

output I want

```
1. Test split h
Here and not .Here and not /Here
```

Just can't figure out the regex to do this

Comment: [`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`](https://regex101.com/r/LvMnge/1) or [`(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`](https://regex101.com/r/LvMnge/2)

Comment: The trick is to use a "lookbehind" as well as a "lookahead".  Use `(?<=` to specify what should come before the split, and `(?=` to specify what should come after.

Comment: Thx both did the trick but (?<=\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu}) works for the Swedish letter also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a easier pattern : `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`

- `(?<= )` ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the current position in the expression.
- `(?= )` asserts that the given subpattern can be matched here, without consuming characters
- both does not consume any characters, very important !

---

`str.split("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])");` old version does not work for other alphabet

Comment: could you explain your regex also?

Comment: Thx looks like it did the trick. But what about the swedish letters åäö? Those wont be included right?

Comment: @HowTheF See second regex in [comment by ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208075/regex-to-split-when-uppercase-after-alphabetic-lowercase-char#comment81365266_47208075): `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`

Comment: @HowTheF If you're parsing Swedish, then use the second option that ctwheels gave you in their comment.  Don't forget to double-up the backslashes.

Comment: @Andreas I'm going to take typing lessons, just so I can keep up with you.

Answer (score 1):

As per my original comment.

### Code

#### Option 1

This option works with ASCII characters (it will not work for Unicode characters). Basically, this works with English text.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LvMnge/2)

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

#### Option 2

This option works with Unicode characters. This works with *any* language.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/LvMnge/2)

```
(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})
```

---

### Explanation

#### Option 1

- `(?<=[a-z])` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a character in the set `a-z` (lowercase ASCII character)
- `(?=[A-Z])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a character in the set `A-Z` (uppercase ASCII character)

#### Option 2

- `(?<=\p{Ll})` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a character in the set `\p{Ll}` (lowercase letter Unicode property/script category)
- `(?=\p{Lu})` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a character in the set `\p{Lu}` (uppercase letter Unicode property/script category)